# Ahref links/anchors moving page down vertically preventDefault();

Tags: html, anchor

This is no doubt very basic HTML, but I have a problem with some anchor tags. I have a page with three overlapping tabs. You click on the tab and the contents come to the front. THe problem is that the page moves vertically down so that the tab is at the top of the page (they are halfway down usually).

Attached is my script to perform the function, as well as a version of the HTML associated.

I think I need to use preventDefault(); somewhere, but not sure where. Any ideas appreciated.

```
<!--Javascript function to brings tabs to the front-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.tab-headers>a").click(function () {
        // Grab the href of the header
        var _href = $(this).attr("href");

        // Remove the first character (i.e. the "#")
        _href = _href.substring(1);

        // show this tab
        tabify(_href);
    });
    tabify();
});
function tabify(_tab) {
    // Hide all the tabs
    $(".tab").hide();

    // If valid show tab, otherwise show the first one
    if (_tab) {
        $(".tab a[name=" + _tab + "]").parent().show();
    } else {
        $(".tab").first().show();
    }
}
// On page load...
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Show our "default" tab.
    // You may wish to grab the current hash value from the URL and display the appropriate one
    // tabify();
});
</script>
```

My HTML is:

```
 <div class="glossary">

    <div class="tab-headers">
    <a href="#tab1"></a>
    <a href="#tab2"></a>
    <a href="#tab3"></a>
    </div>

    <!--Tab 1-->    
    <div class="tab">
    <a name="tab1"></a>
    contents 1 here
    </div>

    <!--Tab 2-->
    <div class="tab">
    <a name="tab2"></a>
    contents 2 here          
    </div>

    <!--Tab 3-->
    <div class="tab">
    <a name="tab3"></a>
    contents 3 here          
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: _“I think I need to use preventDefault(); somewhere, but not sure where.”_ – how about: At the place where you actually handle the click …?

Comment: yeah, but I don't want it to jump, but retain it's position. CBroe, sorry but where do I put that, I don't understand it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the preventDefault() should go here:

```
$("div.tab-headers>a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ....
```

Notice the added (e) after the function. So that would result in the following code:

```
<!--Javascript function to brings tabs to the front-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.tab-headers>a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // normal behavior is stopped
        // Grab the href of the header
        var _href = $(this).attr("href");

        // Remove the first character (i.e. the "#")
        _href = _href.substring(1);

        // show this tab
        tabify(_href);
    });
    tabify();
});
function tabify(_tab) {
    // Hide all the tabs
    $(".tab").hide();

    // If valid show tab, otherwise show the first one
    if (_tab) {
        $(".tab a[name=" + _tab + "]").parent().show();
    } else {
        $(".tab").first().show();
    }
}
// On page load...
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Show our "default" tab.
    // You may wish to grab the current hash value from the URL and display the appropriate one
    // tabify();
});
</script>
```